# MobileFirst 7.1: I'm still required to install Visual C++ Redistributable to use JSON Store on Windows

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, win-universal-app, jsonstore

When our apps were built with MobileFirst 6.3, our customers couldn't use the JSONStore until they manually installed the Visual C++ Redistributable for Studio 2012 on each of their tablet devices. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

I read that in MobileFirst 7.1 iFix 0726, as long as you set this dependency in your jsproj file, you could use the JSONStore and it would automatically work without requiring that each tablet install the Visual C++ redistributable manually.

Here's the dependency I've set:

```
<SDKReference Include="Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=12.0" />
```

I noticed that as part of our build process, it does explicitly build and deploy appx files for the VCLibrary to our MobileFirst app store.

However, after installing our application to the device, and manually installing the packaged VCLibrary appx (hosted in the application center store), the JSON store still doesn't initialize successfully.  To reproduce the issue, I simply call JSONStore.init() and it fails.

I'm forced to manually install the Visual C++ Redistributable package for Studio 2012 from the link above to get the JSON Store to initialize.  Once I have manually installed the redistributable on every tablet device, the JSONStore.init() works fine.

Is this still a manual requirement?  If so, is there any benefit to this dependency.

My device is a Surface 3 tablet.

Comment: We have packaged runtime dll with our MFP project. So, you don't need to manually install it again. Can you please share details on how you are reproducing the issue, device model, MFP iFix version, etc?

Comment: @scott dickerson, please see above question by Vittal...

Comment: To reproduce, simply call JSONStore.init() on a Windows Surface 3 with a Windows Universal app built with MobileFirst 7.1 iFix 0726.  You'll see an error initializing the JSONStore if you don't have the Visual C++ Redistributable for 2012 installed on that machine.

Comment: @scottdickerson I have tried it on Surface tablet which runs on Windows 8.1 RT and failed to reproduce the above issue. I have uploaded my sample [here](https://ibm.box.com/s/nohitrnhv6g79gm35qgn5oflvfa461kf) which you can try with once & also let me know the exact version of windows os of your tablet.

Comment: @scottdickerson, Did you try with the sample which i shared ??

Comment: @scottdickerson Did you try the sample?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, by comparing your out of the box app's jsproj (which did work on my system) to mine, I was able to find the missing piece.  I didn't have this section in my jsproj file

```
<Content Include="..\buildtarget\$(Platform)\msvcr110.dll" >
      <Link>msvcr110.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

I'm not sure that I even need that SDK reference section, as I was able to remove that from your application and it continued to function.